# print `this` variable in android

Tags: android, logging, this

sometimes printf("%p", this) helps to see different instances.

What's the equivalent of that in android?
(to print out address of `this` variable or something unique(it may not be `address`) to the instance)

It seems I can `new` interface like `OnTouchListener` then, how do I print something to differentiate the different instances of them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
android.util.Log.i("Instance", "This is: " + this);
```

By default, the `toString` implementation of `Object` will print the class type plus a hash code which can be considered somewhat equivalent to the *this pointer* in C++.

> The `toString` method for class `Object` returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `'@'`, and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

If an object provides a different implementation of `toString()`, like for instance `String` does, then you can use the above canonical implementation of the base `toString()` method to get the same results.

Comment: `hashCode()` may be overridden, so it may not be distinct

Comment: @newacct: `hashCode()` may not be distinct even if not _overriden_, but good point about `System.identityHashCode(this)`

Answer (score 1):

To get something distinct to the instance, you should use `System.identityHashCode(this)`. It returns what the default implementation of `.hashCode()` in `Object` returns (which may have been overridden in subclasses, so that's why you shouldn't use `.hashCode()` directly), which, according to the documentation, is "As much as is reasonably practical" distinct for distinct objects.